Применение регрессии для временного ряда
Есть датасет, по строкам даны показатели, по столбцам - численные данные за 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030. Т.е каждая строка - это временной ряд. Задача сделать прогноз на 2035 год для каждой строки.
Датасет.

Я делал это так:
forecast_2035 = [] #добавил пустой лист для прогнозированных данных

Затем проходился по каждой строке используя функцию iterrows():
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # Подготовка данных для обучения модели линейной регрессии
    X = df.columns[0:].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # Входные данные: значения временного ряда
    y = row[0:].values.reshape(-1, 1)          # Выходные данные: фактические значения
    
    # Обучение модели линейной регрессии
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
    
    # Прогнозирование значения для 2035 года
    forecast_2035.append(reg.predict([[2035]])[0][0])

И добавил в конец исходного датасета, создав столбец 2035:
df['2035_regression'] = forecast_2035


Судя по полученным данным, все более менее норм.
Вопрос:
1) Можно было бы сделать по другому, т.е пройтись по каждой строке и сделать прогноз, помимо функции iterrows?
2) Как бы вы решали эту задачу? Какие еще мотеды можно использовать?

Линейную регрессию расписать руками и решить в две операции в NumPy.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy использовать numpy хорошая идея кстати. A X и y верно подобрал для лин регрессии?

Добавьте входные данные в вопрос в текстовом виде, а не картинками. Это стандартное требование для таких вопросов.

@CrazyElf добавил

Лучше всё-таки не ссылками, а прямо текстом в вопросе. Пусть даже форматирование данных поедет - я исправлю. Я не могу просто сейчас по ссылкам ходить, а так я мог бы помочь.

А по сути тут действительно получается для каждой строки данных отдельная регрессия строится и кроме как циклом я не очень понимаю, как это можно сделать, ведь у каждой регрессии должны быть свои коэффициенты. Что касается второго вопроса, то я бы как-то попробовал использовать и сами данные тоже в качестве фичи, а не только номер года.

@crazyelf просто для меня было вообще не очевидно использование функции iterrows, т.к не знал что такой есть, думал придется велосипед создавать. Подумал мало ли, может есть другие методы прохождения по строке, какие то другие функции. А насчет методов решения, есть и другие эконометрические методы, например экспонен. сглаживание. И еще интересно почему для y выбран так "= row[0:]", типо наш таргет это же только 2035 год, а мы опять по строке проходимся.
